# How to restore trained classifier/predictor from persistent storage?

Tags: machine-learning

Mathematica 11.3 has the ability to store trained classifier/predictor in the notebook. But how can we restore it in the new session?

Create notebook and measure it's size:

```
FileSize[NotebookDirectory[] <> CurrentValue["NotebookFileName"]]
(* 12.B *)
```

Train classifier and store it in the notebook.

*Interesting note: the option to store will be proposed only if training time is more than 2 seconds.*

```
SeedRandom[0];
X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 50}];
Y = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100000];

c = Classify[X -> Y, Method -> "RandomForest", PerformanceGoal -> "DirectTraining"]
```

[image]

Measure notebook size again:

```
NotebookSave[]
FileSize[NotebookDirectory[] <> CurrentValue["NotebookFileName"]]
(* 6.18639MB *)
```

We have no persistent objects in our notebook:

```
PersistentObjects[All, "Notebook"]
(* {} *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not stored in the `PersistentObject` system. Instead it's cooked into the notebook at the box level. If you run

```
NotebookRead@PreviousCell[] /. _DynamicModuleBox -> Nothing
```

before and after clicking the button you'll see the difference. Alternately if you open it in a text editor that becomes clear.

So just click the button and then evaluate the cell with it in it.

**Example**

Train classifier and store it in the notebook. Then quit kernel or close notebook and open again. X and Y colored blue because they are uninitialized.

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Comment: Hi, May I know how to get the "[[1,1,2]]" numbers in _In[1]_ ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ I just kept digging into successive parts of the data structure until I found what I wanted

Comment: Just to share a solution I used :  _ToString[FullForm[c]]_ | to 'show' the Predictor definition in full. 2. the text is copy-able outside mathematica (which is a need in my task), and reusable by executing :  _c = ToExpression[<the text from step 1>]_ . ( :